# R data.table return no results

Tags: sql-server, r, data.table

This works as I expect and returns 5 rows.

```
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script    
  @language = N'R'    
 ,@script = N' OutputDataSet <- InputDataSet;'    
 ,@input_data_1 = N' select top 5 DataField, FilterField from Table1
     where DataField is not null;'    
  WITH RESULT SETS ((DataField float NULL, FilterField char(75) NULL));
```

This returns an error.

> Msg 11536, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   EXECUTE statement failed because its WITH RESULT SETS clause specified 1 result set(s), but the statement only sent 0 result set(s) at run time.

```
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script    
  @language = N'R'         
 ,@input_data_1 = N' select top 5 DataField from Table1'    
 ,@script = N'
     library(data.table)
     dtf <- data.frame(InputDataSet)
     dt <- data.table(dtf)
     dt[,DataField,by=FilterField]'
WITH RESULT SETS ((DataField float NULL));
```

All the examples I could find for data tables used this kind of syntax, and obviously expected it to work.  `dt[,DataField,by=FilterField]'`

For example, https://www.r-bloggers.com/intro-to-the-data-table-package/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is

```
 **OutputDataSet <-** dt[,DataField,by=FilterField]'
```

Comment: Is there a way to bold the key change inside the code block?

Comment: @Frank If I put that comment in the comments, where do I put the example?

Comment: I posted this on the assumption that others will read the same examples and run into the same problem and because I couldn't find the answer elsewhere.